# Why doesn't the Law of Large Numbers hold here?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, expectation, law-of-large-numbers

This is from an old homework assignment of mine, which I've since turned in.

> Say you have an independent sequence of R.V.s such that $\mathbb{P}(X_n= 2^n) = \frac{1}{2^n} = 1 - \mathbb{P}(X_n = 0)$. Show that:
>   $$\mathbb{E}[X_n] = 1$$
>   and moreover:
>   $$\frac{S_N}{N} \to 0$$
>   almost surely. Why doesn't this contradict the strong LLN?

**Edit:**
So it seems the variables are not identically distributed. How would I prove this (is it obvious/trivial)? Also I was unable to compute the expectation so assistance would that would be appreciated.

Comment: So what are the requirements for the strong law of large numbers to apply?

Comment: The variables just need to be $L^1$ and independent no?

Comment: Ah whoops, looks like I forgot the "identical" part.

Comment: Show $X_1$ and $X_2$ have different distribution.

Comment: This is closely related to (though not exactly the same as) the [St. Petersburg paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/St._Petersburg_paradox).

Comment: How is $S_N$ defined? Is it the sum of $X1 ... XN$?

Comment: @ted: that is what we are assuming.  My guess is that the question actually asked to show $\mathbb E\left[\frac{S_N}{N}\right] = 1$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The variables are not identical since the distribution is different for each $n.$ Both the probabilities and the possible values depend on $n.$ The expectation value can be calculated by the usual formula for discrete variables. $$E(X_n) = \frac{1}{2^n} 2^n + (1-2^{-n})0=1.$$

Comment: The harder part is showing $\frac{S_N}{N} \to 0$.

Comment: @6005 Would you have any tips for that part?

Comment: @rubikscube09 I'll write an answer

Comment: I suspect it is not too difficult to show that $\mathbb{P}\left(\dfrac{S_{2^{2k}_{\,}}^{\,}}{2^{2k}} \ge 2^{-k}\right) \le \dfrac{1}{2^{k-1}}$ and I wonder whether $\mathbb{P}\left(\dfrac{S_{N}^{\,}}{N} \ge \dfrac{2}{\sqrt{N}}\right) \le \dfrac{2}{\sqrt{N}}$ or something similar

Answer (score 5):

Proving $S_N/N\to 0$ can be done using the first Borel-Cantelli lemma. Since $\sum_n P(X_n\neq 0)=\sum (1/2)^n<\infty$, this Lemma implies that with probability one, there will be only finitely many $n$ for which $X_n \neq 0$. This means that the sequence $X_1,X_2,\dots$ is almost surely eventually constant $0$, which implies $S_N/N$ converges to $0$.

Comment: Why doesn't linearity of expectation apply here, such that $E[S_N] = \sum_{n=1}^N E[X_n] = N$ and therefore $E[S_N] / N = 1$?

Comment: @ted It does apply. Why do you ask if it doesn’t always apply?

Comment: Well the requester states (and folks have proved) that $E[S_N]/N \to 0$ as $N \to \infty$. But by linearity of expectation, shouldn't we instead have that $E[S_N]/N \to 1$ as $N \to \infty$? If not, what am I missing?

Comment: In the OP, it is stated (and I proved) that $S_N/N\to 0$ almost surely, not that $E[S_N]/N\to 0$. The difference is subtle and counterintuitive; though the $S_N/N$ is equal to 1 on average for each particular $N$, it is becomes 0 in the limit. @ted

Comment: Thanks. I guess I don't know what $S_N/N \to 0$ almost surely means.

Comment: @ted It just means that with probability one, the random sequence $S_1/1,S_2/2,\dots,$ will converge to $0$. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergence_of_random_variables#Almost_sure_convergence

Answer (score 1):

The hardest part of the question seems to be showing
$$
\frac{S_N}{N} \to 0
$$
almost surely, where $S_N = X_1 + X_2 + \cdots + X_N$. For this, consider the probability that all samples starting with $X_K$ are $0$: $X_K = X_{K+1} = X_{K+2} = \cdots = 0$. This is given by
\begin{align*}
\left(1 - \frac{1}{2^K}\right)
\left(1 - \frac{1}{2^{K+1}}\right)
\left(1 - \frac{1}{2^{K+2}}\right)
\cdots
&= \prod_{n=K}^\infty  \left( 1 - \frac{1}{2^n}\right). \\
\end{align*}
Now, the infinite product $\displaystyle \prod_{n=1}^\infty \left( 1 - q^n\right)$ converges for all complex $|q| < 1$, to the [Euler function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_function) $\phi(q)$.
For $q = \frac12$, it happens to be about $0.28878\ldots$ (see [OEIS](https://oeis.org/A048651)).
Regardless of the numerical value, since it is *positive* (i.e. not zero), it follows that for all $\varepsilon > 0$, there exists a large enough $K$ such that
the probability of $X_K = X_{K+1} = \cdots = 0$ is at least $1 - \varepsilon$.

In the event that $X_K = X_{K+1} = \cdots = 0$, we further deduce that for all $N \ge K$,
$$
S_N = X_1 + X_2 + \cdots + X_N
= X_1 + X_2 + \cdots + X_K \le 2^1 + 2^2 + \cdots + 2^K
< 2^{K+1}.
$$

So $S_N$ is uniformly bounded; thus with probability $1 - \varepsilon$, $\frac{S_N}{N}$ converges to $0$.
Since this holds for all $\varepsilon > 0$, the probability that $\frac{S_N}{N}$ converges must in fact be $1$.
By the definition of almost-sure convergence, we are done.